# How to decide which bars are plotted on top/last in overlay of 2 Pandas bar plots where one plot uses alpha

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code for plotting two overlay bar plots in Pandas, one of which is semitransparent and the other has white edgecolor:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["patch.force_edgecolor"] = True

txt = u'''Category    COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3    
A          0.5               3          Cat1   
B          0.3               5          Cat1 
C          0.7               4          Cat1
A          0.4               3          Cat2
B          0.8               5          Cat2
C          0.3               4          Cat2
A          0.5               3          Cat3   
B          0.3               5          Cat3 
C          0.7               4          Cat3
A          0.4               3          Cat4
B          0.8               5          Cat4
C          0.3               4          Cat4

'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

order = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()




col1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN2').reindex(order)
col1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, legend=False, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='Black', lw=3)

col2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').reindex(order)
col2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, edgecolor='antiquewhite', lw=3, color='black', width=0.2)

ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylim(ax2.get_ylim())

for bbar, cbar in zip(ax.patches, ax2.patches):
    cpos = cbar.get_x()+cbar.get_width()/2.
    bpos = cpos-bbar.get_width()/2.
    bbar.set_x(bpos)

plt.show()
```

The result looks as follows where as one can clearly see the white edgecolor can barely be seen because the black bars are plotted in the background/under the semitransparent bars:
[image: cant see white edgecolor]

Adjusting the code as follows returns the same result as shown in the image above:

```
col1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').reindex(order)
col1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, edgecolor='antiquewhite', lw=3, color='black', width=0.2)

col2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN2').reindex(order)
col2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, legend=False, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='Black', lw=3)
```

If the black bars are plotted on top/last, the white edgecolor should show more clearly.

I tried adjusting the code to this:

```
col1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN2').reindex(order)
col1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, legend=False,  edgecolor='Black', lw=3)

col2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').reindex(order)
col2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, edgecolor='antiquewhite', alpha=0.5, lw=3, color='black', width=0.2)
```

But that clearly shows that the black bars are plotted in the background (again, it seems like they insist on wanting to be in the background, why?):

[image: black are in the background]

So how can one plot the black bars so that they appear on top with clearly distinguishable white edgecolor?

Comment: Yup. look at zorder.